# How to prevent unbound data clearing during sort on DataGridView that has a DataTable as a DataSource

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that is populated with data by binding it with a DataTable.

```
 InputDGV.DataSource = dt1;
```

Later, I am performing calculations and writing the results to the same DataGridView, successfully, using this statement:

```
InputDGV.Rows[Rowi].Cells[column_name].Value = num.ToString();
```

I am essentially displaying the inputs and outputs next to each other. I want the user to be able to sort the columns, but currently when a column is sorted the unbound data in the output cells are lost. Is there a way around this, or do I have to build a way to store the data in the DataSource dt1?

Comment: How is the column added to the `DataGridView`? Is the column added to the `DataGridView` itself or is the column added to the data table?

Comment: It is added to the DataGridView itself.

Comment: In a simplified fashion, I believe that you will have to add a column to the `DataTable`. Because the column you are adding is NOT part of the table, when you click on a column header to do a sort, the whole grid gets refreshed and since part of the grid is unbounded (the column you added) the data will be lost. Try to add this extra column to the `DataTable` after you get the data but before you set the grids data source… like: `dt1.Columns.Add(“ExtraCol”, typeof(string));` then set the grids data source to this table. I am confident this should do the trick as far as the sorting problem.